# How to get Codename one to work on all ios versions?

Tags: codenameone

I followed all the procedures to test on an iphone , it gives me this error after I tried install it , i am using an iphone 7. And I have add the phone name with the UDID already..
[image: The Error]
[image: build hints]
I am not using any cn1libs files , its a simple test app..I am familiarizing myself with the workflow so developement will smoother later.

Comment: Which iOS version are you using?

Comment: Hi Kelvin, Thanks for posting in stackoverflow , please edit the question i.e image description , please add the image .

Comment: Version 13.5.1 @FrancescoGalgani

Comment: Codename One apps should work fine on this OS by default and require no further updating.
What build hints are you using?
Which cn1libs did you include?
Please edit the post then comment back so I can see you made the changes.

Comment: I've found the solution..I had to remove the `ios.debug.archs`